# How to Set WPF Checkbox Text Colo to Gray if Disabled?

Tags: wpf, text, checkbox, colors, triggers

In WPF, when a checkbox is disabled, only the box is grayed out. The text of the checkbox remains black (the default color). How do I make the text also grayed out when checkbox is disabled? The following is the style xaml I've used. The last trigger only changes the box border color, not the text. Target or property does not recognize "Textblock" or "Content". Please help!

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/LightZ;component/Palettes/Brushes.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/LightZ;component/Styles/FillBrush.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style x:Key="CheckBoxFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Rectangle 
        Margin="15,0,0,0"
        StrokeThickness="1"
        Stroke="#60000000"
        StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type CheckBox}" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"    Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Border x:Name="Border"  
          Width="15" 
          Height="15" 
          CornerRadius="0" 
          Background="Transparent"
          BorderThickness="1"
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource text}">
                            <Path 
            Width="12" Height="12" 
            x:Name="CheckMark"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
            Stroke="{StaticResource text}"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            Data="M 0 5 L 3 10 10 0" />
                        </Border>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Data" Value="M 0 7 L 7 0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource highlight}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource highlighttext}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I think this will answer your question : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4dcacfb2-54dd-415e-8b59-844eeba8fb5c/set-foreground-of-contentcontrols-content?forum=wpf

Comment: No. This example has no effect on changing the checkbox text when it's disabled. The example doesn't even work for an independent text block (or so-called content control). The text remains black.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with setting the style in Window.Resources in the xaml as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: It didn't work unless that is the only resource you use for the checkbox. In my case, I've preloaded the resource as shown in this thread and that apparently has dominance over any other resources. Adding your stuff in xaml will result in error: The property resources can only be set once. If inserting the <Style.Triggers> into my resource, there is no effect at all.

Comment: You will have to merge the <Style.Triggers> segment into your existing style for it to work.

Comment: I did, and it still didn't work. I did add the part <Style.Triggers> into the last part of the existing style, but it still didn't work.